# Regex brainfreeze

Tags: regex

Struggling to get my head round this - would appreciate a bit of help if possible from some kind person.

I am trying to extract the last element in a URL, which has the form of this:
https://example.com/notwantedstring/anotherunwantedstring/i-want-this-string/

I want to return "i want this string" (no hyphens).
There can be more than two unwanted strings of arbitrary length. I just want the last element between the penultimate "/" and the last "/". And I don't know what precedes the penultimate "/", and I don't know what the final string is nor how long it is.

So if the regex works correctly, the following

https://www.example.com/abdfsg63/sfdgfv/dfgffk/sf-adfgdg-fgfg-1/

would be rendered "sf adfgdg fgfg 1"

Thanks - if someone knows how to do this and can provide a little bit of explanation, that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reading some regex tutorial? Teaching everything about regex to you is **too broad**.

Comment: What about [`\w+(?=[^/]*/$)`](https://regex101.com/r/nz2ZJt/1)?

Comment: ctwheels' solution will get you what your looking for, but you should probably read up on regex, you can use this site to test stuff out also: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks - I mod'd it to this and it works: \w+(?=[^\/]*\/$)

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/4AV2lL/2):

```
[^-/]*(?=[^/]*/$)
```

Explanation:

- `[^-/]*` matches zero or more characters that are not `-` or `/`. Only match this if there is the following after the match (`(?=)`):

  - zero or more characters that are not `/` (`[^/]*`), followed by,
  - `/`, followed by,
  - `$` the end of the string

You will get a list of matches, then you should concatenate all of them together.

Comment: Thanks - very helpful. I modified it to this and it worked: [^-\/]*(?=[^\/]*\/$)

Comment: @JackSamson if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark!